# Are electrical switches under kitchen sinks common for any utility?

Tags: electrical

So, I was cleaning under the kitchen sink and noticed there is a switch under there! It isn't clearly marked what it's for, I tried playing around with it and the garbage disposal thinking maybe it was a maintenance safety, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

I was just curious, is there a common reason for switches to be placed under the sink?

Comment: I've seen the switch to operate the garbage disposal under the sink. If it's not for that, than maybe a dishwasher disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

A standard snap switch can be used as a safety disconnect for small hard-wired equipment.

I would suspect it is a disconnect for the dishwasher.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A garbage disposal switch, toe kick lights or under cabinet floor heater.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for a sink-specific water heater booster, beverage dispenser.  Have you tried following the wire to see where it goes?